# Heroku/Nuxt not picking up on a mixin?

Tags: heroku, stripe-payments, nuxt.js

I have a button that re-directs to a stripe checkout page - which works fine on my local machine, but I'm receiving this error in my heroku logs when I try it out in production:

```
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664437+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664454+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR  Cannot read property 'subscriptions' of null
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664454+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664455+00:00 app[web.1]: at a.checkActiveSubscription (mixins/stripeSubscription.js:10:0)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664455+00:00 app[web.1]: at a.hasAnyActiveSubscription (pages/profile/billing/index.vue:186:0)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664456+00:00 app[web.1]: at a.hasAnyActiveSubscription (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:29698)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664457+00:00 app[web.1]: at a.render (pages/profile/billing/index.vue)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664457+00:00 app[web.1]: at a.t._render (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.prod.js:6:35273)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664458+00:00 app[web.1]: at node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70637
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664458+00:00 app[web.1]: at Yi (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67201)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664458+00:00 app[web.1]: at io (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70613)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664458+00:00 app[web.1]: at ro (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:70244)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664459+00:00 app[web.1]: at eo (node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:67491)
2021-04-07T14:22:30.664459+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Index.vue:

```
import checkActiveSubscription from "@/mixins/stripeSubscription.js";
export default {
    mixins: [checkActiveSubscription],
....
}

computed: {
   hasAnyActiveSubscription() {
     return this.checkActiveSubscription();
 },
```

stripeSubscription.js:

```
export default {
    methods: {
        checkActiveSubscription() {
            /* 
                check if user has any active subscription
                if so, the user should be able to manage their existing billing
                else - show buttons to create new subscription plans
            */

            let subscriptions = this.$store.getters.user.subscriptions;
            let hasActiveSubscription = false;
            subscriptions.some((element, index) => {
                if (element.status == "active") {
                    hasActiveSubscription = true;
                }
            });
            return hasActiveSubscription;
        },
    }
}
```

Any pointers? Is the issue on Nuxt, Stripe, or Heroku?

My Nuxt store looks like this (user.js inside a folder called store):

```
export const state = () => ({
    CSRFToken: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    user: null,
})

export const mutations = {
    setCSRFToken(state, token) {
        state.CSRFToken = token
    },
    setLoggedIn(state, bool) {
        state.isLoggedIn = bool
    },
    setUser(state, user) {
        state.user = user
    },
}


export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit(vuex, context) {
        console.log("hello?")

        const user = await context.app.$axios.$get(`/account/session/`, {
            credentials: "include",
        });
        vuex.dispatch("setLoggedIn", user.isAuthenticated);

        const { data, headers } = await this.$axios.get('/account/csrf/', {
            withCredentials: true
        });

        const csrfToken = headers["x-csrftoken"];
        vuex.dispatch("setCSRFToken", csrfToken)

        if (user.isAuthenticated) {
            const userDetails = await context.app.$axios.$get(`/account/current/`, {
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken
                },
            });
            vuex.dispatch("setUser", userDetails);
        }
    },

    setCSRFToken({ commit }, token) {
        commit("setCSRFToken", token);
    },

    setLoggedIn({ commit }, bool) {
        commit("setLoggedIn", bool)
    },
    setUser({ commit }, user) {
        commit("setUser", user)
    }
}

export const getters = {
    CSRFToken: state => {
        return state.CSRFToken
    },
    isLoggedIn: state => {
        return state.isLoggedIn
    },
    user: state => {
        return state.user
    }
}
```

and the user is fetched in a computed property as such:

```
user() {
  return this.$store.getters.user;
},
```

Comment: From the error message it seems as though `this.$store.getters.user` is null - where is that being set?

Comment: I'll update my post